# CSS Hover target other element

Tags: html, css, hover, zurb-foundation, target

When hover on the .calltoaction, the background image supposed to scale to 105%. How can I target by CSS? I'm using foundation.css for my html. A codepen has been created as well: http://codepen.io/rezasan/pen/dpyoYO

HTML:

```
<div id="tiles">
<div class="row">
<div class="medium-6 columns nopadleftright tile-img" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/300x300');"></div>
<div class="medium-6 columns nopadleftright text-center">
  <div class="v-align">
    <h1 class="preheader text-center">EXPERIENCES</h1>
    <h1>A Magical Location</h1>
    <p>Text</p>
    <div class="calltoaction"><a href="#">ABOUT</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
 <div class="row">
   <div class="medium-6 columns nopadleftright text-center">
  <div class="v-align">
    <h1 class="preheader text-center">EXPERIENCES</h1>
    <h1>A Magical Location</h1>
    <p>Text</p>
    <div class="calltoaction"><a href="#">ABOUT</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="medium-6 columns nopadleftright tile-img" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/300x300');"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#tiles .row .medium-6 {
    width:45%;
    float:left;
    height: 185px;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding:0 10px;
}

#tiles .row .tile-img{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center; 
    -webkit-background-size: 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;
    transition: background-size .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-size .3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: background-size .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background-size .3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: background-size .3s ease-in-out;
}

#tiles .calltoaction a:hover + .tile-img {
    background-size: 105%;
}
```

Comment: guess you've to write js for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that by pure CSS, because it doesn't work that way (you can't target a **parent** in your case). However you could achieve this by a little jQuery function:

```
$('.calltoaction a').hover(function(){
  $('.tile-img').css('background-size', '105%');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wx38rz5L/2777/

Comment: This works but what I got here is a set of rows with calltoactions and images. When I hover specific "calltoaction" all images will be scaled. I only want specific image of that row to get resized. Please see updated code. When mouse leave, image is still rescaled. I need it to go back to 100%.

Comment: @RezaSan, check https://jsfiddle.net/wx38rz5L/2777/, by the way, you haven't closed your **row**' divs in your initial code

Comment: Yes I missed that row divs. It's working now with the traversing. You are my awesome angel. Thanks so much @Denea Novac

Answer (score 1):

Use background-size:105% on hover

```
    #tiles .row .tile-img:hover {
     background-size:105%;
    }
```